How can I flash message with Laravel Livewire navigate?
I have a problem when trying to show a flash message with Livewire navigate and toastr. If I use normal redirect without navigate, It works as normal with the code below.
$url = route('role.detail', 5);
session()->flash('success', config('app.success'));
return redirect($url);

But when I change my code to use Livewire navigate, the flash message not showing with toastr.
$url = route('role.detail', 5);
session()->flash('success', config('app.success'));
return $this->redirect($url, navigate: true);

I also try to dispatch as well, but it also not working.
$url = route('role.detail', 5);
$this->dispatch('success',['message'=>config('app.success')]);
return $this->redirect($url, navigate: true);

Is there any way that I can flash message when redirect with Livewire naviage? And below is my toastr code for showing flash message.
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        toastr.options = {
          "closeButton": true,
          "debug": false,
          "newestOnTop": false,
          "progressBar": true,
          "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
          "preventDuplicates": false,
          "onclick": null,
          "showDuration": "300",
          "hideDuration": "500",
          "timeOut": "5000",
          "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
          "showEasing": "swing",
          "hideEasing": "linear",
          "showMethod": "fadeIn",
          "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
        };
        window.addEventListener('success', event=>{
            toastr.remove();
            toastr.success(event.detail[0].message);
            
        });
        window.addEventListener('error', event=>{
            toastr.remove();
            toastr.error(event.detail[0].message);
            
        });
    });
    @if(Session::has('success'))
       window.onload = function(){
          toastr.remove();
          toastr.success("{{session('success')}}");
        };
    @endif
    @if(Session::has('error'))
       window.onload = function(){
          toastr.remove();
          toastr.error("{{session('error')}}");
        };
    @endif
</script>


Livewire session-based flash messages are not automatically preserved across navigation. You could use Livewire's events to manually display flash messages or pass the message as part of the navigation.

Using events:

Use dispatch() to initiate event:
    $url = route('role.detail', 5);
    $this->dispatch('showFlashMessage', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => config('app.success')]);
    return $this->redirect($url, navigate: true);

And in your blade, use this to listen for the given event:
<div>
    <script>
        Livewire.on('showFlashMessage', ({type, message}) => {
            alert(`${type}: ${message}`);
        });
    </script>
</div>

Read more about events here.

Passing the message as part of the navigation

Add message param to your url:
$url = route('role.detail', ['id' => 5, 'flash_message' => config('app.success')]);
return $this->redirect($url, navigate: true);

Inside your mount() method, retrieve the param:
if (request()->has('flash_message')) {
   $this->dispatch('showFlashMessage', [
      'type' => 'success', 
      'message' => request('flash_message')
   ]);
}

And then display it like this:
<div>
    <script>
        Livewire.on('showFlashMessage', ({type, message}) => {
            alert(`${type}: ${message}`);
        });
    </script>
</div>


After trying several ways to solve this problem, I found this one works for me.
@if(Session::has('success'))
   @script
        <script>
            toastr.options.timeOut = 900;
            toastr.success("{{session('success')}}");
        </script>
   @endscript

